# Examples of compact negatively curved constant curvature manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking for concrete examples of negatively curved constant curvature manifold. The only example of negatively curved constant curvature manifold is the hyperbolic plane. Are there any easy examples of such manifolds which are compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any compact orientable surface of genus $>1$ carries a metric with constant negative curvature

Comment: Can we say anything similar about the case when metric is induced by embedding space? Also, can you please elaborate your statement and/or provide references/explain or give intuition why is this the case?

Comment: @Vlad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Hyperbolic_Riemann_surfaces

Comment: Reference : 167 p. Riemannian geometry - Gallot Hulin and Lafontaine

Comment: Are there simpler examples if I relax the condition to be only compact and negatively curved?

Comment: I can not understand your question. only compact ?

Comment: Only compact and negatively curved but not necessarily of constant curvature. I am thinking of the poincare disk, but it is not compact.

Comment: @zach The Pointcare disk has constant sectional curvatures.